# CodeIgniter RESTful works offline but not online

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, rest

I believe the reason why I have this problem is because of `.htaccess` (although they are the same in offline and online).

```
http://localhost/myProject/api/webservice/getUsers -> Works
http://myProjectDomain.com/api/webservice/getUsers -> Doesn't work, error: 500 Internal Error
```

.htaccess from root folder:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>
```

In my point of view I might need to create another rule? Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/api/webservice/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

I found my answer in this topic: [malformed header from script. Bad header=1: index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939676/malformed-header-from-script-bad-header-1-index-php)

A few weeks ago I had to changed my `REST_controller.php` file in order to receive large amount of data from the webservice. Although I found a little bug, when the amount of data was too big, it wouldn't retrieve it completely.

For example, the format JSON.

```
[{data: {'values': '1'}, {'values': '2'}]
```

Now this is large scale only retrieves me:

```
[{data: {'values': '1'}, {'values': '2'
```

Yes, it misses the `}]`, therefore the JSON format wasn't good.
So i've change a little the code, from:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
```

to:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output) + 15);
```

But I made a basic mistake that I wouldn't do if I was coding in a typed language.
The values weren't actually summed but concatenated. Solution:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . (strlen($output) + 15));
```