# Error 500 malformed header from script. Bad header in PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a site thats works without any issues on wamp but once i host it in a bluehost account i get error 500 on both submit form and any ajax calls.

example of an error is

```
malformed header from script. Bad header=user_auth.php: fetch_cities.php
```

the user_auth.php thats the login script no need of posting it here.

Am using php 5.6 i did google and some of the solutions i found were like to check inside php.ini, no line showing `magic_quotes_cpg=on` or `register_globals = on` . Any pointers on what could be the issue is appreciated

fetch_cities.php

```
<?php

include('../../bin/initaccess.php');
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
$number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['number']);
if($number == 0){

echo "<option value=''>-- Select City --</option>";
$sql = "SELECT city_name FROM cities";

}else{

$sql = "SELECT city_name FROM cities WHERE city_name = '$city'";

}

$result = $db->query($sql);
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$city_name = $row1['city_name'];

?>

    <option <?php if($city_name == $city){ echo "selected"; } ?> value='<?php echo $city_name; ?>'><?php echo $city_name; ?></option>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: have you checked htaccess file and other server settings as well as required modules are enable

Comment: Provide us with headers your sending in those calls.

Comment: @DawidZbiński i don't quite understand what exactly you want me to provide. the same scripts work in wamp server .

Comment: @PragneshChauhan i did check htaccess file . For modules i can see some are failing to start although am not sure if they are needed

Comment: Do you set any headers in your auth script? manually? take a look on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939676/malformed-header-from-script-bad-header-1-index-php

Comment: are you using any CMS or Framework?

Comment: @DawidZbiński no i dont. its just a login script.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan its a CMS

Comment: @dannjoroge it's probably going to be hard to guess what is that without showing off your php code and the code responsible for responses in your CMS. We won't guess for years, it's not a simple solution to this one, it might be a lot of things.

Comment: let me post an example of one of the responses.

Comment: Do you redirect user using `header('Location: ...');` ? after logging in or at some point?

Comment: @DawidZbiński yes i usually do that

Comment: i have just shared my script that is called through ajax

Comment: Well, script doesn't seem to be helpful. But be careful, the queries you had there are SQL injectable, try using PDO and it's prepared statements for query binding. But back to main question, check if your php code does not use `echo`, `var_dump` or `print_r` before your `header('Location: ...)`. It might be helpful if you share initaccess.php file with us, too.